# Extract string after last delimiter for each line in text file

Tags: batch-file

Backstory: I am trying to automate the process of creating InternetShortcut (.url) files via a batch file that creates one .url file for each address in a text file (one address per line). Dealing with two files: inputFile.txt and internetShortcut_creator.bat. In command prompt, I run:

```
internetShortcut_creator.bat inputFile.txt
```

Here are the contents of the two files mentioned above:

```
:: inputFile.txt containing one address per line
https://www.google.com/local/myfilename.pdf
https://www.wikipedia.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/slideshow.pptx
```

```
:: internetShortcut_creator.bat

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET inputFile=%1

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%inputFile%) do (

    set address=%%i
    :: replace "/" with " "
    set address=!address:/= !

    :: attempt to extract the text after the last space, assign to %name%
    for /f %%j in ("!address!") do set name=%%j

    :: echo each of the extracted strings
    echo !name!
)
ENDLOCAL
```

Pretty lost here, any help would be appreciated.
Mike

Comment: You need, and have already enabled delayed expansion, so use it. `set "address=!address:/= !"`, `for /f %%j in ("!address!") do set "name=%%j"`, and `echo !name!`.

Comment: @Compo thank you for the tip. This correctly echos out the first token in each address, so I am one step closer to extracting the last token of each address. Above code has been updated to reflect these changes.

Comment: Is this not all you need `@For /F "UseBackQ EOL=: Delims=" %%G In ("%~1") Do @Echo(%%~nxG`?

Comment: @Compo It 100% is. That one-liner provides exactly the processing I was hoping for. Now I will be decoding why it works.... A thousand thanks to you, and graciously, from the novice sitting in front of this keyboard.

Comment: I would not advise you get in the habit of using double colons for comments inside a code block.

Comment: @Squashman I actually _did_ run into problems using a double colon for commenting inside code blocks (and REM solved it for me) - are there any good explanations you can link to or share here? Thanks